# IE9 crashes and reopens

Tags: apache-flex, internet-explorer, flash

I have a Flex application which opens in a new window when I click on javascript link in another window. If I close the flex application window, using the browser close button, while it's still loading, more precisely, just before the datagrid is displayed, the screen kind of hangs for less than a second, if I close the screen in that moment, IE9 crashes and the following message is displayed:

> A problem with this webpage caused Internet Explorer to close and reopen the tab

I've tried all the solutions I found online, but none worked:

- adding the website to compatibility view
- using different versions of flash player
- updating the java plugin
- disabling/enabling plugins
- reset internet explorer settings
- install the latest updates
- using microsoft tool "fix it"
- use software rendering instead of GPU rendering

Comment: what is your question? could you share an url or some code?

Comment: I'm asking whether someone has encountered this issue and found a workaround

Comment: You should improve your question by first fixing the title, since the problem is definitely related to the Flash Player plugin. Then you should list the Flex version, Flash Player version and exact version of the browser. Did you search the Flash Player bug database for entries, maybe this is known issue?

Comment: @bork999 I've searched everywhere, and like I said in my question, I tried different versions of Flash Player. The problem doesn't happen in IE8

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem using Firefox and Chrome. This happens to me when I am receiving a long list of data that has to be processed before it is shown to the user or if I am using a graphically intensive component that makes the browser hang due to the processor load that is being applied to it.

Try checking your Task Manager when this happens and check if the browser is using all your processor time, if this is the case then you need to work on making your code more efficient by reducing data pre-processing and doing more on the fly when the user is scrolling through data or by using List-based components instead of Repeater components since the latter tend to make everything extremely slow even if you are using simple text renderers.